# Put object properties inside of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

It could be pretty easy but i can't seem to find how to merge 2 objects in Javascript

e.g: object one

```
[
  {
    "name":"Actief",
    "children":[
      {
        "name": "Vaste activa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Immateriële vaste activa",
            "children": null
          },
          {
            "name": "Materiële vaste activa",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Terreinen en gebrouwen",
                "children": null
              },
              {
                "name": "Installaties, machines & uitrustingen",
                "children": null
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Object two:

```
[
   {
      name: "Immateriële vaste activa",
      data: [1.3, 2.4, 3.6, 0.2, 1.1],
      year: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
   },
   {
      name: "Terreinen en gebrouwen",
      data: [1000300, 44589, 908887, 255667, 110000],
      year: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
   },
   {
      name: "Installaties, machines & uitrustingen",
      data: [12000, 23000, 38000, 203000, 11111],
      year: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
   }
]
```

So to explain this a little bit more, i am building an AngularJS application where in this example i'm doing `ng-repeat` inside of an `ng-repeat` so i make some sort of tree of the first JSON object. The lowest level (sometimes 5 deep) have to contain data and years to, so i tried to figure out how i can merge these multidimensional arrays/objects.

The best will be, to my oppinion, is to have something like this:

```
{
   "name": "Terreinen en gebrouwen",
   "children": null,
   "data": [1000300, 44589, 908887, 255667, 110000],
   "year": [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
},
```

It will still be hard to publish this in my view but i think i will be a big step further if my objects/arrays will look like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fairly simple to do.

All you need is to iterate over *Object two*'s items and then find object with the same name in the *Object one*

Our two objects:

```
var obj1 = [
  {
    "name":"Actief",
    "children":[
      {
        "name": "Vaste activa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Immateriële vaste activa",
            "children": null
          },
          {
            "name": "Materiële vaste activa",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Terreinen en gebrouwen",
                "children": null
              },
              {
                "name": "Installaties, machines & uitrustingen",
                "children": null
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

var obj2 = [
   {
      name: "Immateriële vaste activa",
      data: [1.3, 2.4, 3.6, 0.2, 1.1],
      year: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
   },
   {
      name: "Terreinen en gebrouwen",
      data: [1000300, 44589, 908887, 255667, 110000],
      year: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
   },
   {
      name: "Installaties, machines & uitrustingen",
      data: [12000, 23000, 38000, 203000, 11111],
      year: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
   }
]
```

then the function to add properties if names are same or go into children array if there are any and try again :

```
function addProps(obj, o){

        for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
            var o2 = obj[j];
            if(o2.name === o.name) {
                o2.data = o.data; 
                o2.year = o.year; 
            } else {
                if(o2.children != null) addProps(o2.children, o);
            }
        }

}
```

now iterate over *Object two* `obj2` in my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj2.length; i++) {
    var o = obj2[i];
    addProps(obj1, o);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Molda it works! Thank you very much. I just see so many code a day that sometimes i just can't seem to find the right method to accomplish such easy things...

Comment: Hi Molda, I don't know if there exists a way and you can update above code to a situation where i have e.g. 3000 records in obj1 and the same amount in obj2? Now it takes a shameless lot of time to iterate over all the records.

Comment: Do you really need to work with this amount of data on the client? I can't imagine a situation when I would need that. If you can explain more in details where and how you're getting the data there might be different solution to your problem. I don't think there's a way to improve performance with this much of data.

Comment: We'll i do, there are 2 different places where i get my data from. 1. PostgreSQL database, where i read the rows out with a PHP class and convert it to a object in PHP itself. 2. With a websocket connection to an API. Here i get arount the same amount of data, but i' m never sure (API sends object itself) I can't just exclude these 2 different ways of getting my data.

Comment: It feels like bad design. Can't you use some filters to get less data at a time and use pagination to show max 100 rows per page?